# Slicing pandas dataframe by looking for character "in" string

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to extract a set of rows from a dataframe based on whether a string in that row contains a given substring.

For example, say I have

`testdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':['abc','efc','abz'], 'B':[4,5,6]})`.

I want to get the rows containing the substring `'ab'` in column `'A'`.

I tried `testdf.loc[lambda df: 'ab' in df['A'], :]`, but got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-86c436129f94> in <module>()
----> 1 testdf.loc[lambda df: 'a' in df['A'], :]

/Users/justinpounders/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1292 
   1293         if type(key) is tuple:
-> 1294             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1295         else:
   1296             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)

/Users/justinpounders/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    782     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
    783         try:
--> 784             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
    785         except IndexingError:
    786             pass

/Users/justinpounders/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    906         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
    907             if is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 908                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    909 
    910                 # we have yielded a scalar ?

/Users/justinpounders/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1465         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1466         self._has_valid_type(key, axis)
-> 1467         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1468 
   1469 

/Users/justinpounders/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _get_label(self, label, axis)
     91             raise IndexingError('no slices here, handle elsewhere')
     92 
---> 93         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
     94 
     95     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=0):

/Users/justinpounders/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in xs(self, key, axis, level, copy, drop_level)
   1747                                                       drop_level=drop_level)
   1748         else:
-> 1749             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   1750 
   1751             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

/Users/justinpounders/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:
-> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   1948 
   1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3977)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.Int64Engine._check_type (pandas/index.c:7634)()

KeyError: False
```

What confuses me is that `testdf.loc[lambda df: df['A'] == 'abc', :]` does not five an error: it returns the one row containing the value `abc`.  So it appears that there something about the `'ab' in df['A']` boolean that is not correct...

I am using python 2.7 and pandas 0.18.1 in a Jupyter (4.0.6) notebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [67]:
testdf[testdf['A'].str.contains('ab')]

Out[67]:
     A  B
0  abc  4
2  abz  6
```

What you tried doesn't make sense firstly:

```
In [70]:
'ab' in testdf['A']

Out[70]:
False
```

but what you're really trying to do is test 'ab' in each element of that column:

```
In [71]:
testdf['A'].apply(lambda x: 'ab' in x)

Out[71]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

However, there is no need for `apply` here when there is a vectorised method

What you tried here:

```
testdf.loc[lambda df: 'ab' in testdf['A']]
```

raised a keyerror because the lambda returned a scalar `False` which can't be used to index the whole df, but `testdf.loc[lambda df: df['A'] == 'abc', :]` works because `df['A'] == 'abc'` returns a boolean mask which can be used to mask the entire df

Also the `lambda` is unnecessary in the `loc`:

```
testdf.loc[testdf['A'] == 'abc', :]
```

would've worked, if you think about it, all you did was provide a lambda for your df which is no different to the above